# How can I modify an AngularJS Bootstrap dropdown / select so that it does not use jQuery?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I saw a really good example of a AngularJS Bootstrap type of Select directive:

http://jsfiddle.net/cojahmetov/3DS49/

This meets most of my needs but it uses jQuery and we are not using that library.

The jQuery used in this example is very minimal but I do not know how I could replace the element locators that look like this:

Can anyone give me any pointers as to how I could replace this:

```
switch (attrs.menuType) {
  case "button":
    $('button.button-label', element).html(item.name);
    break;
  default:
    $('a.dropdown-toggle', element).html('<b class="caret"></b> ' + item.name);
    break;
}
```

So that it would work without `jQuery`? Ideally I am hoping that someone knows enough to maybe come up with a version based on the version in the `ui-bootstrap`. Perhaps this could even be something that might be added to ui-bootstrap for others to use.

Comment: What browsers are you targeting/supporting?

Comment: Perhaps assigning the value directly to HTML is not a good idea - you could use the scope object for that. You can check my answer for the current alternative.

Comment: Check the answer. You have the wrong approach here: you don't need to use .html()

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Idea in that Fiddle was nice but I found the implementation kinda messy. So what can one do? Well, write an alternative `dropdown` directive on top of `ui-bootstrap`, of course!

Hope you find this helpful. It should be really easy to use.

**Usage**

```
<dropdown is-button 
          ng-model="vm.item" 
          items="vm.items" 
          callback="vm.callback(item)">
</dropdown>
```

So you pass in the `ng-model` which holds the initial selection, if any. New value is set from the directive. In `items` you have collection of `id-name` pairs to choose from and a `callback` function if you need it. If you specify the `is-button` attribute, you'll get a button-stylish dropdown control.

Then the controller could look like the following.

**Controller**

```
// Controller
app.controller('Ctrl', function() {
  var vm = this;

  // items collection
  vm.items = [{
      id: 0,
      name: 'London'
    },{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Paris'
    },{
      id: 2,
      name: 'Milan'
    }];

  // current item
  vm.item = null; // vm.items[1];

  // directive callback function    
  vm.callback = function(item) {
    vm.fromCallback = 'User selected ' + angular.toJson(item);
  };
});
```

Logic for the `dropdown` directive is pretty simple, really.

**Directive javaScript**

```
// Dropdown directive 
app.directive('dropdown', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^ngModel',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=', // selection
      items: '=',   // items to select from
      callback: '&' // callback
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });

      scope.default = 'Please select item';
      scope.isButton = 'isButton' in attrs;

      // selection changed handler
      scope.select = function(item) {
        scope.ngModel = item;
        if (scope.callback) {
          scope.callback({ item: item });
        }
      };
    },
    templateUrl: 'dropdown-template.html'
  };
});
```

**Directive HTML template**

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>

  <!-- button style dropdown -->
  <button ng-if="isButton" 
          type="button" 
          class="btn btn-primary"
          ng-bind="ngModel.name || default">
  </button>
  <button ng-if="isButton" 
          type="button" 
          class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" 
          dropdown-toggle>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- no button, plz -->
  <a ng-if="!isButton" 
     class="dropdown-toggle"
     dropdown-toggle href
     ng-bind="ngModel.name || default">
  </a>
  <span ng-if="!isButton" class="caret"></span>

  <!-- dropdown items -->
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"> 
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <a href="#" 
         ng-bind="item.name" 
         ng-click="select(item)"></a>
    </li> 
  </ul>

</div>
```

Here's the look & feel of the initial implementation. In addition to the sample you provided, you'll get back the whole object and not just the `id`.

[image]

---

Related Plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/bLWabx using angularjs 1.4.0-beta.3 and ui-bootstrap 0.12.0.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to come up with this very nice solution. I will try this out today and see if I have any questions.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution! 

However, when I select an item, my page loads to the root. How can we stop the default behaviour of 'ui.bootstrap.dropdown' to load page upon selection?

Comment: I found something that works. I passed the $event into the select method of the directive and then call preventDefault() on this event. Will wait to see your solution, not sure if I am doing the correct way. thank-you!

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. I have updated my answer/plunker to prevent default behaviour on `element`'s `click` event. Or you can just remove the `href="#"` part of items but then you need to apply CSS to show "nicer" cursor.

Comment: If you are using the latest ui.bootstrap make sure you replace `dropdown` and `dropdown-toggle` with the new `uib-dropdown` and `uib-dropdown-toggle`

Answer (score 3):

This solution only supports IE9+ if you need to support legacy browsers I can find another solution and update.

http://jsfiddle.net/3DS49/160/

```
scope.selectVal = function (item) {
    function selector(sel, htmlCont)
    {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll(sel);
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(elems, function(el, i){
            el.innerHTML = htmlCont;
        });
    }
    switch (attrs.menuType) {
        case "button":
            selector('button.button-label', item.name);
            break;
        default:
            selector('a.dropdown-toggle', '<b class="caret"></b> ' + item.name);
            break;
    }
    scope.doSelect({
        selectedVal: item.id
    });
};
```

Comment: It's not vorking well, when you create second dropdown: when value is selected in second, it is changed in first also... http://jsfiddle.net/6jj222w7/ the same worked in original - http://jsfiddle.net/v33sbzgy/

Comment: It is safer to assign correctly the values to the scope, instead of raw-using .html calls. You also need to properly define the template with the desired bindings

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: I was right, you don't need to use .html() in this example, and is a bad practice in general. Notice how I used the `scope` object to accomplish the same result: http://jsfiddle.net/3DS49/162/

For the minimal example you showed here, You could use `angular.element` instead of `$` or `jQuery`. `angular.element` is a subset but it supports .html().

However, it is still a bad practice, since the content could be put in `scope` and the html content could be set as a direct binding in the button templates.

**Edit**: angular.element does not support selectors. You should use a native approach for that (getElementById and its friends). However, ensure you're not using jquery-specific selectors, like :first. E.g.:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".myclass");

//it is up to you to iterate over the elements and call angular.element(element).html(yourValueHere) on each element.

//NOTE: you can get document from $windowProvider.$get().document, or $window.document, depending on the place (you will use $window.document in this case).
```

**Edit**: check browser support [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll) - there's no native angular way to support selectors.

For a practical implementation of the particular case, it is safe to see  @ChrisFrank 's answer. However, remember you can wrap each of the elements iterated (e.g. in his answer) with `angular.element` function to get a jqLite (AngularJS's built in subset of jQuery - you don't need any additional library) object.